# OPENAI-Langchain issues: while trying to read data from csv and convert into embeddings using the text-ada-002, I got the following error

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

We are getting the following error while trying to read data from csv and convert into embeddings using the text-ada-002  in langchain
 `500 {'error': {'message': 'The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about that! You can retry your request, or contact us through our help center at help.openai.com if the error persists. (Please include the request ID __ in your message.)', 'type': 'server_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}} {'Date': 'Tue, 27 Jun 2023 17:40:22 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '366', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'openai-organization': '', 'openai-processing-ms': '31836', 'openai-version': '2020-10-01', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains', 'x-ratelimit-limit-requests': '3000', 'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens': '1000000', 'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '2999', 'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens': '753591', 'x-ratelimit-reset-requests': '20ms', 'x-ratelimit-reset-tokens': '14.784s', 'x-request-id': '', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '7ddf78bf3bb71749-SJC', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400'}.`
We are not above the token limit still facing rate limit error on the tokens
`'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens': '1000000', 'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '2999', 'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens': '753591'`

I didn't encounter this problem last week, and I didn't make any changes to the code. It just suddenly had this error yesterday

chunking or delaying the requests.